# I need to share my Printer on my OSX Imac with a windows 8 via wireless network

Tags: macos

I am trying to share my epson CX660 over a wireless network with a Windows 8 HP laptop.
I am using bonjour on the windows box to try to access my epson printer, no luck seeing the printer